# Why am I getting null pointer exception in this program when using enhanced for loop

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am getting a null pointer exception in the selectAllStudent Method.
When I am using foreach loop but When I am using a normal loop it is working fine.
Please explain the reason. Thank you

**Driver Class**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[] sdb = new Student[2];
        try {
            for (Student s : sdb) {
                s = takeInput();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
        selectAllStudent(sdb);
    }

    static void selectAllStudent(Student[] sdb) {
        for (Student s : sdb) {
            s.printStudentDetails();               // Getting NullPOinterException here
        }
    }
    public static Student takeInput() throws IOException{
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the details ");
        System.out.print("ROLL      :"); int rollno = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        System.out.print("NAME      :"); String name = in.readLine();
        System.out.print("BRANCH    :"); String branch = in.readLine();
        return (new Student(rollno,name,branch));
    }  
}
```

**Student Class**

```
public class Student {

    private int rollno;
    private String name;
    private String branch;

    Student(int rollno, String name, String branch) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
        this.name = name;
        this.branch = branch;
    }

    void printStudentDetails() {
        System.out.println("ROLLNO  :" + rollno);
        System.out.println("NAME    :" + name);
        System.out.println("BRANCH  :" + branch);
        System.out.println("-------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I know what is null pointer exception but I am not sure why I am getting a null pointer exception over here

Comment: If I am using a normal for loop I am not getting an exception but when I am using for each loop I am getting the exception.

Comment: @RohitSharma: If you know what a null pointer exception is, you should be able to identify which reference is null. You may then have a question about *why* it's null, but that wouldn't be the same question.

Comment: Additionally, please read the help explaining how to format code - it's *not* done with quoting (`> ...`)

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried formatting that way but there was some problem , I wasn't able to post the question. I'll learn the proper way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not assigning a new `Student` to the array in this `for` loop.

```
for (Student s : sdb) {
    s = takeInput();
}
```

The `takeInput` method is returning a `Student` properly, but you've assigned it to a local reference `s`, not as an element in the array `sdb`.  The elements of the array remain `null`, and the `NullPointerException` comes from attempting to call `printStudentDetails` on `null` in the `selectAllStudent` method.

You can convert the enhanced `for` loop to a standard `for` loop, assigning the `Student` with an array access expression.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sdb.length; i++)
{
    sdb[i] = takeInput();
}
```

Comment: I am not getting any error in the normal for loop. Is there any way to do this using enhanced for loop ?

Comment: No, because `s` isn't the array element.  You can change what `s` refers to, but that doesn't change what the array refers to.

Comment: That means only values can be accessed using enhanced for loop but can't be assigned ?

Comment: That is correct.  In addition, you could call a method on `Student` that changes one of its fields (mutates the `Student`), but you still can't replace it in the array.